# How to Read XElement contents containing Sharepoint List Structure?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing

I want to bind the MultipleCheckbox items from Choice Column of sharepoint List to asp.net CheckBoxListItem using c#.
I am retriving information of List using XELEMENT as:

In .cs file:

```
XElement listStructure;

listStructure = proxy.GetList("WebsiteSubscriber");
```

here am getting XML as:

```
  <List DocTemplateUrl="" DefaultViewUrl="/Lists/WebsiteSubscriber/AllItems.aspx" MobileDefaultViewUrl="" ID="{2C8A80EA-38C5-48F7-9D7D-400D445A5E64}" Title="WebsiteSubscriber" Description="" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/itgen.png" Name="{2C8A80EA-38C5-48F7-9D7D-400D445A5E64}" BaseType="0" FeatureId="00bfea71-de22-43b2-a848-c05709900100" ServerTemplate="100" Created="20130417 02:18:11" Modified="20130424 09:27:11" LastDeleted="20130419 04:46:25" Version="5" Direction="none" ThumbnailSize="" WebImageWidth="" WebImageHeight="" Flags="545263616" ItemCount="13" AnonymousPermMask="0" RootFolder="/Lists/WebsiteSubscriber" ReadSecurity="1" WriteSecurity="1" Author="8" EventSinkAssembly="" EventSinkClass="" EventSinkData="" EmailAlias="" WebFullUrl="/" WebId="198e057a-38e8-410a-8358-ed95f77d18ea" SendToLocation="" ScopeId="e2cbf2fd-93e4-408d-bd4e-320321734b8c" MajorVersionLimit="0" MajorWithMinorVersionsLimit="0" WorkFlowId="" HasUniqueScopes="False" NoThrottleListOperations="False" HasRelatedLists="" AllowDeletion="True" AllowMultiResponses="False" EnableAttachments="True" EnableModeration="False" EnableVersioning="False" HasExternalDataSource="False" Hidden="False" MultipleDataList="False" Ordered="False" ShowUser="True" EnablePeopleSelector="False" EnableResourceSelector="False" EnableMinorVersion="False" RequireCheckout="False" ThrottleListOperations="False" ExcludeFromOfflineClient="False" EnableFolderCreation="False" IrmEnabled="False" IsApplicationList="False" PreserveEmptyValues="False" StrictTypeCoercion="False" EnforceDataValidation="False" MaxItemsPerThrottledOperation="100000" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
  <Fields>
    <Field ID="{03e45e84-1992-4d42-9116-26f756012634}" RowOrdinal="0" Type="ContentTypeId" Sealed="TRUE" ReadOnly="TRUE" Hidden="TRUE" DisplayName="Content Type ID" Name="ContentTypeId" DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="ContentTypeId" ColName="tp_ContentTypeId" FromBaseType="TRUE" />
    <Field ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Name="Title" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Title" Group="Base Columns" Type="Text" DisplayName="Title" Required="FALSE" FromBaseType="TRUE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" MaxLength="255" Version="1" ColName="nvarchar1" RowOrdinal="0" />
    <Field ID="{34ad21eb-75bd-4544-8c73-0e08330291fe}" ReadOnly="TRUE" Type="Note" Name="_ModerationComments" DisplayName="Approver Comments" Hidden="TRUE" CanToggleHidden="TRUE" Filterable="FALSE" Sortable="FALSE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="_ModerationComments" FromBaseType="TRUE" ColName="ntext1" />
    <Field ID="{bc91a437-52e7-49e1-8c4e-4698904b2b6d}" ReadOnly="TRUE" Type="Computed" Name="LinkTitleNoMenu" DisplayName="Title" Dir="" DisplayNameSrcField="Title" AuthoringInfo="(linked to item)" EnableLookup="TRUE" ListItemMenuAllowed="Prohibited" LinkToItemAllowed="Prohibited" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="LinkTitleNoMenu" FromBaseType="TRUE">
      <FieldRefs>
        <FieldRef Name="Title" />
        <FieldRef Name="LinkFilenameNoMenu" />
      </FieldRefs>
      <DisplayPattern>
        <IfEqual>
          <Expr1>
            <LookupColumn Name="FSObjType" />
          </Expr1>
          <Expr2>1</Expr2>
          <Then>
            <Field Name="LinkFilenameNoMenu" />
          </Then>
          <Else>
            <HTML><![CDATA[<a onfocus="OnLink(this)" href="]]></HTML>
            <URL />
            <HTML><![CDATA[" onclick="EditLink2(this,]]></HTML>
            <Counter Type="View" />
            <HTML><![CDATA[);return false;" target="_self">]]></HTML>
            <Column HTMLEncode="TRUE" Name="Title" Default="(no title)" />
            <IfEqual>
              <Expr1>
                <GetVar Name="ShowAccessibleIcon" />
              </Expr1>
              <Expr2>1</Expr2>
              <Then>
                <HTML><![CDATA[<img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" class="ms-hidden" border="0" width="1" height="1" alt="Use SHIFT+ENTER to open the menu (new window)."/>]]></HTML>
              </Then>
            </IfEqual>
            <HTML><![CDATA[</a>]]></HTML>
            <IfNew>
              <HTML><![CDATA[<img src="/_layouts/1033/images/new.gif" alt="]]></HTML>
              <HTML>New</HTML>
              <HTML><![CDATA[" class="ms-newgif" />]]></HTML>
            </IfNew>
          </Else>
        </IfEqual>
      </DisplayPattern>
    </Field>
    <Field ID="{82642ec8-ef9b-478f-acf9-31f7d45fbc31}" ReadOnly="TRUE" Type="Computed" Name="LinkTitle" DisplayName="Title" DisplayNameSrcField="Title" ClassInfo="Menu" AuthoringInfo="(linked to item with edit menu)" ListItemMenuAllowed="Required" LinkToItemAllowed="Prohibited" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="LinkTitle" FromBaseType="TRUE">
      <FieldRefs>
        <FieldRef Name="Title" />
        <FieldRef Name="LinkTitleNoMenu" />
        <FieldRef Name="_EditMenuTableStart2" />
        <FieldRef Name="_EditMenuTableEnd" />
      </FieldRefs>
      <DisplayPattern>
        <FieldSwitch>
          <Expr>
            <GetVar Name="FreeForm" />
          </Expr>
          <Case Value="TRUE">
            <Field Name="LinkTitleNoMenu" />
          </Case>
          <Default>
            <Switch>
              <Expr>
                <GetVar Name="MasterVersion" />
              </Expr>
              <Case Value="4">
                <HTML><![CDATA[<div class="ms-vb itx" onmouseover="OnItem(this)" CTXName="ctx]]></HTML>
                <Field Name="_EditMenuTableStart2" />
                <HTML><![CDATA[">]]></HTML>
                <Field Name="LinkTitleNoMenu" />
                <HTML><![CDATA[</div>]]></HTML>
                <HTML><![CDATA[<div class="s4-ctx" onmouseover="OnChildItem(this.parentNode); return false;">]]></HTML>
                <HTML><![CDATA[<span>&nbsp;</span>]]></HTML>
                <HTML><![CDATA[<a onfocus="OnChildItem(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;" onclick="PopMenuFromChevron(event); return false;" href="javascript:;" title="Open Menu"></a>]]></HTML>
                <HTML><![CDATA[<span>&nbsp;</span>]]></HTML>
                <HTML><![CDATA[</div>]]></HTML>
              </Case>
              <Default>
                <HTML><![CDATA[<table height="100%" cellspacing="0" class="ms-unselectedtitle itx" onmouseover="OnItem(this)" CTXName="ctx]]></HTML>
                <Field Name="_EditMenuTableStart2" />
                <HTML><![CDATA["><tr><td width="100%" class="ms-vb">]]></HTML>
                <SetVar Name="ShowAccessibleIcon" Value="1" />
                <Field Name="LinkTitleNoMenu" />
                <SetVar Name="ShowAccessibleIcon" Value="0" />
                <HTML><![CDATA[</td><td><img src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif" width="13" style="visibility:hidden" alt=""/></td></tr></table>]]></HTML>
              </Default>
            </Switch>
          </Default>
        </FieldSwitch>
      </DisplayPattern>
    </Field>
    <Field ID="{5f190d91-3dbc-4489-9878-3c092caf35b6}" Hidden="TRUE" ReadOnly="TRUE" Type="Computed" Name="LinkTitle2" DisplayName="Title" DisplayNameSrcField="Title" ClassInfo="Menu" AuthoringInfo="(linked to item with edit menu) (old)" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="LinkTitle2" FromBaseType="TRUE">
      <FieldRefs>
        <FieldRef Name="Title" />
        <FieldRef Name="LinkTitleNoMenu" />
        <FieldRef Name="_EditMenuTableStart" />
        <FieldRef Name="_EditMenuTableEnd" />
      </FieldRefs>
      <DisplayPattern>
        <FieldSwitch>
          <Expr>
            <GetVar Name="FreeForm" />
          </Expr>
          <Case Value="TRUE">
            <Field Name="LinkTitleNoMenu" />
          </Case>
          <Default>
            <Field Name="_EditMenuTableStart" />
            <SetVar Name="ShowAccessibleIcon" Value="1" />
            <Field Name="LinkTitleNoMenu" />
            <SetVar Name="ShowAccessibleIcon" Value="0" />
            <Field Name="_EditMenuTableEnd" />
          </Default>
        </FieldSwitch>
      </DisplayPattern>
    </Field>
    <Field ID="{39360f11-34cf-4356-9945-25c44e68dade}" ReadOnly="TRUE" Hidden="TRUE" Type="Text" Name="File_x0020_Type" DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE" DisplayName="File Type" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="File_x0020_Type" FromBaseType="TRUE" ColName="nvarchar2" />
    <Field Type="Text" DisplayName="Email" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" MaxLength="255" ID="{bf605e59-6807-47de-87ac-617b2c8df00b}" SourceID="{2c8a80ea-38c5-48f7-9d7d-400d445a5e64}" StaticName="Email" Name="Email" ColName="nvarchar3" RowOrdinal="0" />
    <Field Type="MultiChoice" DisplayName="Area" Required="FALSE" EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE" Indexed="FALSE" FillInChoice="FALSE" ID="{16cc1615-a490-44de-a870-c7ebe603e2cc}" SourceID="{2c8a80ea-38c5-48f7-9d7d-400d445a5e64}" StaticName="Area" Name="Area" ColName="ntext2" RowOrdinal="0">
      <Default>Articles</Default>
      **<CHOICES>
        <CHOICE>Articles</CHOICE>
        <CHOICE>Websites</CHOICE>
        <CHOICE>Books</CHOICE>
      </CHOICES>**
    </Field>
    <Field ID="{1d22ea11-1e32-424e-89ab-9fedbadb6ce1}" ColName="tp_ID" RowOrdinal="0" ReadOnly="TRUE" Type="Counter" Name="ID" PrimaryKey="TRUE" DisplayName="ID" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="ID" FromBaseType="TRUE" />
    <Field ID="{c042a256-787d-4a6f-8a8a-cf6ab767f12d}" Type="Computed" DisplayName="Content Type" Name="ContentType" DisplaceOnUpgrade="TRUE" RenderXMLUsingPattern="TRUE" Sortable="FALSE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="ContentType" Group="_Hidden" PITarget="MicrosoftWindowsSharePointServices" PIAttribute="ContentTypeID" FromBaseType="TRUE">
```

I want to get above values following from XML.

```
<CHOICES>
            <CHOICE>Articles</CHOICE>
            <CHOICE>Websites</CHOICE>
            <CHOICE>Books</CHOICE>
  </CHOICES>
```

Comment: What elements highlighted in italics? Why not just specify the elements explicitly instead of having us scan that behemoth of an XML document, which by the way isn't well formed as you aren't closing `<Fields>` or <List>`...

Comment: all text is too long so cant paste all text sorry plz check i have modifed it..! sorry for inconvininece!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you fix your XML, this does what you want:

```
var choices = (from n in xml.Descendants()
              where n.Name.LocalName == "CHOICES"
              select new
              {
                    CHOICES = n.Elements().Select(x => x.Value).ToList()
              }).ToList();
```

Will give you a list of the anonymous type `CHOICES` elements that contain your `CHOICE` element values. Example output:

[image]

**Edit**

See comments:

```
var choices = (from n in xml.Descendants()
               where n.Name.LocalName == "CHOICE"
               select n.Value).ToList();
```

This will return a list of the following string values:

- Articles
- Websites
- Books
- 0;#Approved
- 1;#Rejected
- 2;#Pending
- 3;#Draft
- 4;#Scheduled

Comment: Here is my full xml files structure: fileswap.com/dl/XbSY9BEMpB this is what i am getting result after quering the XElement. the content is this file is result of Xelement and not the xml file. PLZ HELP !

Comment: What... you said you want to retrieve the `CHOICE` values from the XML you posted, this code does that. What's the issue?

Comment: sorry @DGibbs i tried your code with my above XElement return result but it wont works!

Comment: Just to clarify, the return result is the XML structure you posted in your question right?

Comment: yes! it you want to see the whole file it have pasted the link of file which contains the result of XElement

Comment: I just ran the code against the entire XML response you linked and it **works perfectly fine**... what format is the data supposed to be in? Do you just want the values of every choice element or does the structure matter...?

Comment: i need the values only such as 'Articles,Websites,Books' which can bind to asp.net checkboxlist box

Comment: Perhaps you should have stipulated that to begin with? I have edited my answer, this new query will return every `CHOICE` value within the XML regardless of structure.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28800/discussion-between-shekhar-shete-and-dgibbs)

Comment: I have edited the answer to return all choice values regardless of structure

Comment: i need only first 3values 'Articles,Books,Websites' i am new to XElement & LINQ please let me know?